How to retrofit tub faucet as wall mounted sink
I've got an Chicago Faucet Co. antique gooseneck I want to use as my kitchen sink. I also want to use a matching one on my bathroom sink (pictured).
The fixtures have two 1/2" male ends with a nut and washer. I can't figure out how to make this work. I have no cabinets or drywall installed in either room so I've got a clean slate to do something unconventional. I just need to be able to install it once the drywall is up and be able to have two shutoffs in the cabinet below.
I've made a silly mockup of the parts I. ** think ** could work but I welcome any issues anyone sees with this, either from a practical standpoint or that of an inspector.
Thanks!




Mmmm...nice old leaded brass. Tasty... you might want to run a search on de-leading the surface of brass items; one common method (NASA came up with it though I can't find a good link; it's commonly known in brewing circles) is to briefly submerge in 2 parts 5% vinegar and 1 part 3% hydrogen peroxide just until the surface turns a buttery yellow. If the solution turns green, you left it too long (dissolving copper and exposing more lead) and should rinse, mix new solution, and try again for less time. The solution should look clear when you are done.

Your idea for shut-offs is good.
Others' ideas about flex supply lines within the wall are correct (don't do it).
I would use copper pipe (or PEX if allowed in your region) from the shut-offs up to the blocking, then attach to drop-ear elbows. Attach the faucet directly to the drop-ear elbows or use brass nipples and couplings. You don't need "something that'll spin"; the faucet is equipped with unions so that the wall connections can be made without rotating the entire unit.
Note- it is hard to tell scale from your photos, but to me the male threads on the faucet connections look like 3/4" MPT as opposed to 1/2". Old "clawfoot" tub faucets typically had 3/4" pipe thread connections.


You don't want to run braided lines in the wall if that is what your diagram is showing.
Old fixtures used to be based off galvanized iron pipe which was all FIP/MIP.  In your case you just want the pex in the wall to end with a MIP nipple that extends out of the wall so you can attach your faucet.
So pretty much your drawing except the braided hose is pex in the wall.

Hmmm. So what's sticking out of the wall after it's finished and I attach the faucet? It can't be MIP because the faucet is. It can't be FIP because you can't rotate the faucet to attach. Has to be something that'll spin like a ballcock, hence my suggestion to use the braided hose and the shutoffs left in the cabinet.

Hopefully you have access to the back side of the faucet (other side of wall).

Oh I see, good point.  You can get sharkbite to MIP.  These will spin on the pex pipe.  While I don't usually like using sharkbite / pushfittings or propress where they can't be seen, they are all certified for in wall use and warrantied for 25+ years.

One way to do this might be to have a piece of pex that sticks out of the wall for the connection but can be pushed back into the wall when you mount the faucet.  If you need to service you can unsecure the faucet and pull it toward you with the pex slack.  You could even use a standard MIP to crimpex connector in this case as you could crimp it after you've connected to the faucet.

I know Copper is "old school"  But in my mind this installation needs copper soldered to the faucet. The inside dimension may well take 3/4 pipe that is soldered on with 90 deg. bends to take the pipe parallel to the wall either up or down depending on which way the water source comes. This would be similar to a shower mixing valve. The copper can be terminated in fittings to meet pex.
If you must have shutoffs, run the pipe down to the cabinet. Turn to enter the cabinet and there place your shutoffs which are connected to the incoming water piping.
As an aside, after soldering to the faucet "sharkbite" connectors can be used.  This is not endorsed by me rather a suggestion as in some locals the push connect fittings are allowed in walls.
